# Is there a way around RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object?

Tags: python, opencv, recursion, tkinter

I am making a funktion that calls itself, but i'm getting error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object, Is there a way around this. More specifically i am getting it for line 35, ok, frame = cap.read()
I cant put a while loop because of the .after funktion in my program.

```
import cv2
from tkinter import *
import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack()

print("[INFO] Making variables")
ImageSource = 0
window_name = "AutoCam"
width = 600
height = 800
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
print("[INFO] Made variables ")


def ShowFrame(frame):
    print("[INFO] making image.")
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    print("[INFO] After 10 initializing")
    lmain.after(10, CheckSource)
    print("[INFO] Showed image")


def CheckSource():
    ok, frame = cap.read()

    if ok:
        print("[INFO] Ok is triggered")

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            print("[INFO] Exiting app after command")

        ShowFrame(frame)

    else:

        lmain.after(10, CheckSource())


CheckSource()
root.mainloop()
```

Any and all help would be very appreciated. 
Could someone also explain how to avoid this for future use?

[EDIT]

```
the error message is:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 52, in <module>
   CheckSource()
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
 [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 35, in CheckSource
  ok, frame = cap.read()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python 
object
```

Comment: dont get any error when i run your code.

Comment: what? i get a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: you have to run it while not having the camera plugged in...

Comment: because the app is suppose to automatically show camera feed once connected

Comment: Please include the full and exact error message.

Comment: ok, the answer is editied

Comment: I do not get an error and your code appears to be working as intended. I suspect your connection to your camera is bad and you need to write a condition to handle this error.

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: You have extra parens: `.after(..., CheckSource())` - change to `.after(..., CheckSource)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the stack trace you can identify that the recursion is happening in line 49 (it is the line that is being executed many times)

```
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
File "C:/Users/Gotta/Documents/AutoCamPy.py", line 49, in CheckSource
  lmain.after(10, CheckSource())
 [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
```

The reason why it is reaching the recursion limit is because the `.after` function (https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) expects a callback function as the second argument, but you are passing the **result** of calling `CheckSource` instead. You should pass `CheckSource` instead of `CheckSource()` as the second argument:

`lmain.after(10, CheckSource)`

Answer (score 1):

To handle this in a simple way you can write a try/except statement to catch this error. Until you know exactly what the error is you can use a catch all but I would recommend you hand the specific error once you know what it is.

That said I changed a few things in your code to clean it up a bit and to follow the PEP8 standard more closely.

You really should do `import tkinter as tk` instead of using `*`. This will help prevent overwriting of methods that have been imported.

Next your lambda was over kill just do `root.quit` instead. We want to save a reference to the command instead of executing it and we do this by removing the parenthesis. The same problem existed with your 2nd after statement.

Lastly you import `PIL` and then specifically import from PIL. You do not need to do both. If you just need `Image` and `ImageTk` then just do `from PIL import Image, ImageTk` and if you need many things from PIL then you can simple do `import PIL` and use the `PIL.` prefix from there.

Here is your cleaned up code with a try/except statement. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2


root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', root.quit)
lmain = tk.Label(root)
lmain.pack()
ImageSource = 0
window_name = "AutoCam"
width = 600
height = 800
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ImageSource)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)


def show_frame(frame):
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(10, check_source)


def check_source():
    try:
        ok, frame = cap.read()
        if ok:
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                cv2.waitKey(0)
            show_frame(frame)
        else:
            lmain.after(10, check_source)
    except:
        print('Connection failed for some reason!')


check_source()
root.mainloop()
```